# build system (watch,concat,minify) for centralized javascript css template

Tags: php, concatenation, build-automation, minify

Just finishing a new redesign (responsive html5) and I'm wondering what's the simplest way to run an automatic build system.

My site's templates all grab the JavaScript and CSS locations from two include files, so it's not like I need a build system that goes through my whole site minifying and tweaking, etc.

Essentially I'm imagining the workflow is like this:

- if I upload changes to my JS or CSS directories, the system notices the updates and calls a minify and concatenation process.
- the php files that call the JS and CSS minified/concatenated files can generate a filename with an md5 hash for setting long expires.

What's the simplest way to do this? If it's just a couple of files do I really need to install Grunt, etc? Would it be best just to use inotifywait?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/mrclay/minify

Answer (score 0):

you can use [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/), it's a very user-friendly task runner. But first you have to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Then you can imagine whatever worflow to automate, write it and gulp.js will execute on demand.

Here is a good way to start with gulp : [getting started with gulp](https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp)

If it will be a little time investment to set-up but widely useful in the long run !